# Setting up TileCache to make use of Mapnik and OpenStreetMaps

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, tilecache

First of all, I'd say that I'm completely newb at maps related stuff... I am trying to install TileCache and configure it to use Mapnik to render tiles from OpenStreetMaps. I managed to setup the Tilecache basic CGI conf, but now I do not know how can I continue with setting up Mapnik and my own tiles because I am not able to find any tutorial on the net explaining the steps for a complete TileCache setup for OSM and Mapnik (neither in TileCache's web it is explained), and, since it is the first time I deal with WMS and maps rendering and so on, I find difficult to understand the proccess... Could somebody help me, please?

BTW, I need this to run on Windows Vista/7

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the [OSM Mapnik tutorial on the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik) or any of the [other tutorials online](http://weait.com/content/build-your-own-openstreetmap-server)?

Now you will find it much harderto do this on Windows, so for every single component of those tutorials, you are going to need to find a Windows port - not fun.

Do yourself a favor and download [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) which will provide 90% of the components you need ported to Windows already.